# Is there any supercapacitor that is hermetically sealed?

Tags: supercapacitor

1. Does high altitude affect supercapacitors?
2. At high altitudes mostly hermetically sealed capacitors are used, so is there any supercapacitor that is hermetically sealed?

Comment: Could you refer me to what a non-hermetically sealed electrochemical capacitor would look like?

Comment: A non-hermetically sealed capacitor is a standard capacitor (They do not have tight sealing) Link : https://www.mouser.in/c/?marcom=163886073

, Hermetically sealed : https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/c/cornell-dubilier/hermetically-sealed-aluminum-electrolytic-capacitors

Comment: ah! nice! Ankit, I learned something today: so, technically, "hermetical seal" is just when the contents of a package are completely packaged in an airtight manner. And that's the case for any electrolytic capacitor type I'm aware of, including supercapacitors. However, what you're looking for seems to be a package that's "marketing-wise" hermetically sealed, i.e. something that follows specific standardizations for environmental conditions (pressure). So, I don't know that. I think if you need something like that, you will have to read datasheets and contact vendors. You probably need

Comment: certificiation to some specific military or civil standard as well, not just the label "hermetically sealed", and it's not really helpful if strangers on the internet tell you something, you need to get it in writing from the supplier.

Comment: According to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor) all supercapacitors are hermetically sealed.

Comment: If it's for non-commercial application, e.g., short exposure to lowered pressure in a "near-space" (balloon) experiment, I'd test it in a vacuum chamber as-is -- it likely would survive. Cold might be another issue, though...

Comment: @Finbarr Thanks for the information.